# Angular: How to dynamically add components to html in an string, and bootstrap it?

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to do this:

You have a code like this:

```
<body ng-app="MyApp">
<div id="content"><button onclick="addCode()">Add Code</button></div>
</body>
```

now, the function "addCode()" is doing this: (with jQuery library)

```
function addCode(){
  $("content").html("<hello-world></hello-world>");
}
```

This  tag is an angular component, code:

```
'use strict';
        angular.module('MyApp', []).component('helloWorld', {
            templateUrl: 'template.html',
            controller: function () {
                this.greet = 'Hello World';
            }
});
```

And finnally, the template.html has the next code:

```
<p>{{$ctrl.greet}}</p>
```

How can I make that script start the application after clicking the button, so in the web will appear "Hello World", instead of `{{$ctrl.greet}}`, inside the paragraph?

In other words, I want to make angular re-load / re-bootstrap the document searching for components tag to load them dynamically.

This works perfectly if you set `<body><hello-world></hello-world></body>` and load the document, I want to set the component and load it after web is loaded first.

Comment: Try to execute function on ng-if="myFunction()" or a value $scope.myvalue set by  addCode()

Comment: I can't think of any reason to ever do this that using ng-if wouldn't do better. You really aren't supposed to arbitrarily inject angular components with jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

When making DOM changes outside of Angular, you need to notify Angular about it. This can be done with the [$scope.$digest()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) command.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

This is the code, finnally I got it, wasn't so hard.

in ur script:

```
angular.module('MyApp', []).component('helloWorld', {
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        controller: function ($http) {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.updateHello = function (str) {                    
                ctrl.greet = 'Hello '+str;
            };
            ctrl.updateHello('World')
        }
});
```

in ur html template:

```
<button class="ng-binding" ng-click="$ctrl.updateHello ('Angular')">UPDATE</button>
<div>{{$ctrl.greet}}</div>
```

in ur html main file or layout:

```
<hello-world></hello-world>
```

:)